# How to tell JSdoc argument is optional

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

I want to pass to a method either a String or nothing.

My JSDoc looks like this:

```
/**
 * Explain...
 * @param {String|undefined} someVar
 */
runMethod(someVar) {}
```

I call the method either with an argument or without.

```
this.runMethod('a'); // all fine
this.runMethod();    // marked as missing arg
```

Calling it without an argument my IDE (WebStorm) undelines it as an error.

My solution is to define the method like this:

```
runMethod(someVar=undefined) {}
```

Is there a better way to let WebStorm know, the argument is optional?

Comment: The [documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#optional-parameters-and-default-values) seems to show how you might do that.

Comment: `@param {string} [somebody] - Somebody's name.` or `@param {string=} somebody - Somebody's name.` so bypassers don't have to visit above link

Comment: @Yogi @Dimava Thanks to both answers. Both are what I was looking for. Especially the `[]` to mark an optional argument. I used it in the past, but did not think about it this time. Thanks - if one of you could answer the question, I can assign a correct answer.